# How to prevent puppetserver tmpdir 100% usage

Tags: puppet, centos7

I have installed puppetserver-6.10.0-1 on 16 cores/8G RAM virtual machine with CentOS 7. Puppet server manages 700+ other machines. In /etc/sysconfig/puppetserver I added "-Djava.io.tmpdir=/var/tmp" to JAVA_ARGS, where was 15G free space. After two days this directory is full with jruby-* directories and puppetserver is broken

So my questions:
Is it wrong behavior?
Is there a way to prevet full filling or I just need more disk space?

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved by adding RAM to machine and increasing the Xmx java option in /etc/sysconfig/puppetserver:

```
JAVA_ARGS="-Xms7g -Xmx20g -Djruby.logger.class=com.puppetlabs.jruby_utils.jruby.Slf4jLogger -Djava.io.tmpdir=/var/tmp"
```